# How to make an input field draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a dropdown/input field, but I want to put a draggable event into it. When I drag it for the first time, it moves smoothly, but when I start to edit the text inside the input field, I can't seem to drag it around anymore. I've been researching the on the draggable methods but no luck.

Basically I have a `<div>` wrapped around the dropdown/input field where the draggable event is attached.

```
<div class="draggable">
    <select>
       <option>
    </select>
    <input>
</div>
```

It's something like that. Below is the link for the code that has the dropdown/input field, but it still has the draggable event.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUxr4/406/

EDIT:
Here is the updated code, but the draggable is not working. I don't know why.
http://jsfiddle.net/9SPvQ/1/

Comment: Are you sure you have posted relevant jsFiddle? Where is the draggable part?

Comment: I can't implement the draggable part because I don't know how to.

Comment: Just include jQuery UI from left panel and of course, include relevant code in JS part

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the supposedly working draggable dropdown should be working but I can't seem to find a way to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dispatch event because jQuery UI draggable prevent drag behaviour on input element. Now, to still have input element responsive, you can use following workaround:

### DEMO jsFiddle

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
       $(this).data('preventBehaviour', true);
    }
});

$(".draggable :input").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var mdown = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    mdown.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    $(this).closest('.draggable')[0].dispatchEvent(mdown);
}).on('click', function(e){
    var $draggable = $(this).closest('.draggable');
    if($draggable.data("preventBehaviour")){
        e.preventDefault();
        $draggable.data("preventBehaviour", false)
    }
});
```

Comment: WOW nice code.  Thorny problem.